# I am using dio library for the http response but is not updating the listview flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

The data is not updating in the list view flutter but the response is printing in the log. i want to show the data in the list view but the API is working the Video is not updating and i am not receiving any data in the card. if any idea there to resolve this issue.

Below the code i am hitting the API to get response but is not displaying anything(video).
I am using the stream builder to achieve the data displaying check the below code and tell me where is the issue

```
class RespondedVideos extends StatefulWidget{

  var slug;
  RespondedVideos({Key key,@required this.slug}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  respondedVideosState createState() => respondedVideosState();

}

    class respondedVideosState extends State<RespondedVideos> {

      VideoPlayerController _controller;
      List data = new List();
      var respondercookie;
      String video_url = "";

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        readCookie();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child:Container(
                  height: 100,
                  child: Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3.0, 60.0, 3.0, 0.0),
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    child:  Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text("Feedback: ")
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text("Status: ")
                              //+data[position].name,style:TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent)
                            ],
                          )
                        ]
                    ),
                  ),

                )
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            Flexible(
                flex: 2,
                child:Container(
                    height: 1000,
                    child: StreamBuilder(
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.tealAccent),
                              ),
                            );
                          } else {
                            return  ListView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0),
                                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                                  if(data[position]["source_url"] != null)
                                    video_url = data[position]["source_url"];
                                  _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(video_url
                                  )
                                    ..initialize().then((_) {
                                      setState(() {});
                                    });
                                  _controller.setVolume(30.0);
                                  return new Container(
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Card(
                                          child: Container(
                                            width: 230.0,
                                            child: Column(
                                              // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                Stack(
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Container(
                                                      child: _controller.value.initialized
                                                          ? AspectRatio(
                                                        aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                                                        child: VideoPlayer(_controller),

                                                      )
                                                          : Container(),
                                                    ),

                                                    Column(
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                            vertical: 80.0, horizontal: 160.0)),
                                                        RaisedButton(
                                                          color: Colors.transparent,
                                                          onPressed: () {
                                                            setState(() {
                                                              _controller.value.isPlaying
                                                                  ? _controller.pause()
                                                                  : _controller.play();
                                                            });
                                                          },
                                                          child: Icon(
                                                            _controller.value.isPlaying
                                                                ? Icons.pause
                                                                : Icons.play_arrow,
                                                            color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),

                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                  );
                                }
                            );
                          }
                        }
                    )
                )
            ),

          ],
        );

      }  
Future<String>getUserVideoDetails(String slug) async{
    String  url= "http://3.208.3.10:3000/api/v1/feedbacks/"+slug+"";
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(url),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json","cookie":respondercookie},
    );
    setState(() {
      var convertDataToJson = json.decode(response.body);
      data =convertDataToJson['responses'];
      print(data);
    });
    return "suceess";
  }



  void readCookie() async{
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    respondercookie = prefs.getString('respondedcookie')??'';
    getUserVideoDetails(widget.slug);
  }
```

Comment: Please, add code where you are hitting the API!

Comment: @Taym i have edited the code please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work:

Fetching data do not print inside setState:

```
Future<String>getUserVideoDetails(String slug) async{
    String  url= "http://3.208.3.10:3000/api/v1/feedbacks/"+slug+"";
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(url),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "cookie": respondercookie},
    );
    var convertDataToJson = json.decode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      data = convertDataToJson['responses'];
    });
    print(data);
    return "suceess";
  }
```

You don't need `StreamBuilder` you can just use `ListView.builder`:

```
Flexible(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(
                height: 1000,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0),
                    itemCount: data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                      if (data.isEmpty) {
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                Colors.tealAccent),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      if (data[position]["source_url"] != null)
                        video_url = data[position]["source_url"];
                      _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(video_url
                      )
                        ..initialize().then((_) {
                          setState(() {});
                        });
                      _controller.setVolume(30.0);
                      return new Container(
                          child: Center(
                        child: Card(
                          child: Container(
                            width: 230.0,
                            child: Column(
                               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Stack(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      child: Container(),
                                      child: _controller.value.initialized
                                          ? AspectRatio(
                                        aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                                        child: VideoPlayer(_controller),

                                      )
                                         :  Container(),
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Padding(
                                            padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                vertical: 80.0,
                                                horizontal: 160.0)),
                                        RaisedButton(
                                          color: Colors.transparent,
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              _controller.value.isPlaying
                                                  ? _controller.pause()
                                                  : _controller.play();
                                            });
                                          },
                                          child: Icon(
                                            _controller.value.isPlaying
                                            ? Icons.pause
                                            Icons.play_arrow,
                                            color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ));
                    }))),
```

Comment: I have tried this but the video is not playing and it is showing blank screen

Comment: Thanks @Taym  But I want to play a list of videos using list view.builder but the video player is showing blank page

Comment: Yeah but I respond to your question about `I am using dio library for the http response but is not updating the listview flutter
Ask Question`! you can upvote the answer!!

Comment: I have edited the code if you have any idea respond me